# is it possible to create a custom code inside infusionsoft?

Tags: infusionsoft

I would like to add a custom code inside my page in infusionsoft, is this possible? I have only tried manupulating the database using an external system, but i dont know what I should do if it needs to be inside the infusionsoft system. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are going to need more information to provide a help answer. Yes you can add javascript to your shopping cart pages or order form pages.

You can use the [Infusionsoft API](https://developer.infusionsoft.com/docs) to make changes to the database.

No you cannot change anything in the actual Infusionsoft application (code wise). It is hosted by Infusionsoft and you have no access to the source code.

Comment: I need to add a custom php code. for example when adding a new invoice. I need to compute the total balance and update a field. Thanks for the reply btw.

Comment: what you have explained can be easily done on your client(outside infusionsoft) end. i would recommend using data service(https://developer.infusionsoft.com/docs/read/Data_Service) to manipulate tables(https://developer.infusionsoft.com/docs/read/Table_Documentation) and achieve results.